# How to fix Design View Errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently started using Visual Studio to develop C++ Windows Applications using forms, i downloaded CLR/.... windows Forms to starting working with forms but, the Design View Always showing this error in Picture Below:

[image]

**How to Fix this, as I am new to Visual Studio?**

**Note:** I am Using ***Visual Studio 2019***.

Comment: It is a flaw in the designer for C++/CLI, you need to use Build > Build first, then you can open the form.  The project templates for this kind of project were removed 8 years ago, Microsoft has very little reason to fix bugs.

Comment: I tried Building the project, but no luck so far.